# How to use CommMonitor in gem5

Tags: gem5

I want to record the access details of the cache. I saw some answers, saying that CommMonitor can help. But no more details were found.

[How to trace the data that is going through caches and DRAM memory in gem5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63193082/how-to-trace-the-data-that-is-going-through-caches-and-dram-memory-in-gem5)

[Obtaining physical address trace from GEM5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61052733/obtaining-physical-address-trace-from-gem5/63892830#63892830)

The above are some answers about CommMonitor.
I have some questions about CommMonitor?

1. First of all, can Commmonitor be used for DerivO3CPU or only TimingSimpleCPU? I tried it on DerivO3CPU and there was output. But somewhere I seem to hear that it cannot be used for DerivO3CPU.
2. My understanding of CommMonitor is that it is like a filter. The data flowing through it is recorded. For example, add commMonitor between l2 and membus,

   ```
        system.monitor2 = CommMonitor()
        system.monitor2.trace = MemTraceProbe(trace_file = "CT_mon2.trc.gz")
        system.monitor2.slave = system.l2.mem_side
        system.membus.slave = system.monitor2.master
        system.l2.cpu_side = system.tol2bus.master
   ```

The output format is :

```
 11500: system.monitor2: Forwarded read request
  77000: system.monitor2: Latency: 65500
  77000: system.monitor2: Received read response
 103000: system.monitor2: Forwarded read request
 104000: system.monitor2: Forwarded read request
 165000: system.monitor2: Latency: 62000
 165000: system.monitor2: Received read response
 170000: system.monitor2: Latency: 66000
 170000: system.monitor2: Received read response
 194500: system.monitor2: Forwarded read request
 200500: system.monitor2: Forwarded read request
 243000: system.monitor2: Latency: 48500
 243000: system.monitor2: Received read response
 249000: system.monitor2: Latency: 48500
 249000: system.monitor2: Received read response
 267500: system.monitor2: Forwarded read request
 269500: system.monitor2: Forwarded read request
 274000: system.monitor2: Forwarded read request
```

**The generated CT_mon2.trc.gz file is a binary file after decompression, what should I do to see the data inside? It would be better if I can output the address and data**

3. How to use it between l1dcache and cpu?

Answer (score 1):

3. How to use it between l1dcache and cpu?

Edit gem5/src/cpu/→ BaseCPU.py as following and don't forget to build after any changes you do to the src folder:
[image]

You can use flags(as follows) to see whats passes through this master-slave interface.

`build/X86/gem5.opt --debug-flags=CommMonitor --debug-file=trace.txt.gz configs/learning_gem5/part2/simple_cache.py`

Find trace.txt.gz in the m5out folder.